# ml.net vector with dynamic length

Tags: c#, ml.net

I´m using ml.net to build a model, but I can't figure out how to build a model from a complex object with a list of other objects, of varying length. Example code:

```
public void Test()
{
   List<SomeModel> data = new List<SomeModel>()
   {
        new SomeModel //Note first object has 3 'OtherModel's
        {
            SomeLabel = 1,
            Features = new List<OtherModel>
            {
                new OtherModel
                {
                    SomeFirstFeature = 1,
                    SomeOtherFeature = 2,
                    SomeThirdFeature = 3
                },
                new OtherModel
                {
                    SomeFirstFeature = 4,
                    SomeOtherFeature = 5,
                    SomeThirdFeature = 6
                },
                new OtherModel
                {
                    SomeFirstFeature = 4,
                    SomeOtherFeature = 5,
                    SomeThirdFeature = 6
                }
            }
        },
        new SomeModel //Note second object has 2 'OtherModel's
        {
            SomeLabel = 2,
            Features = new List<OtherModel>
            {
                new OtherModel
                {
                    SomeFirstFeature = 7,
                    SomeOtherFeature = 8,
                    SomeThirdFeature = 9
                },
                new OtherModel
                {
                    SomeFirstFeature = 10,
                    SomeOtherFeature = 11,
                    SomeThirdFeature = 12
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    //I have tried flattening the data, since ml.net does not support nested data.
    var flattenedData = data.Select(x => new FlattenedModel
    {
        SomeLabel = x.SomeLabel,
        SomeFirstFeatures = x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeFirstFeature).ToArray(),
        SomeOtherFeatures = x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeOtherFeature).ToArray(),
        SomeThirdFeatures = x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeThirdFeature).ToArray()
    }).ToList();

    var flattenedData2 = data.Select(x => new FlattenedModel2
    {
        SomeLabel = x.SomeLabel,
        SomeFirstFeatures = new VBuffer<float>(x.Features.Count ,x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeFirstFeature).ToArray()),
        SomeOtherFeatures = new VBuffer<float>(x.Features.Count, x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeOtherFeature).ToArray()),
        SomeThirdFeatures = new VBuffer<float>(x.Features.Count, x.Features.Select(y => y.SomeThirdFeature).ToArray())
    }).ToList();

    var mlContext = new Microsoft.ML.MLContext();
    IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<FlattenedModel2>(flattenedData2);

    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "SomeFirstFeatures", "SomeOtherFeatures", "SomeThirdFeatures")
         .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("SomeFirstFeatures"))
         .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("SomeOtherFeatures"))
         .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("SomeThirdFeatures"))
         .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree(labelColumnName: "Label"));
    
    var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);
    //If i use 'FlattenedModel':
    //Throws
    //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //'Schema mismatch for input column 'SomeFirstFeatures':
    //expected known-size vector or scalar, got VarVector<Single>
    //Arg_ParamName_Name'

    //If i use 'FlattenedModel2':
    //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //'Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features':
    //expected Vector<Single>, got VarVector<Single> Arg_ParamName_Name'
}

public class SomeModel
{
    [Column("label")]
    public float SomeLabel { get; set; }
    public List<OtherModel> Features { get; set; }
}

public class OtherModel
{
    public float SomeFirstFeature { get; set; }
    public float SomeOtherFeature { get; set; }
    public float SomeThirdFeature { get; set; }
}

public class FlattenedModel
{
    [Column("label")]
    public float SomeLabel { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public float[] SomeFirstFeatures { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public float[] SomeOtherFeatures { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public float[] SomeThirdFeatures { get; set; }
} 

public class FlattenedModel2
{
    [Column("label")]
    public float SomeLabel { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public VBuffer<float> SomeFirstFeatures { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public VBuffer<float> SomeOtherFeatures { get; set; }
    [VectorType()]
    public VBuffer<float> SomeThirdFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried flattening the model using arrays and VBuffers, but none with succes.

I found a solution, if the length just isn't known before runtime, but still no solution to variable lengths of the vectors:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6151

Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Many hours of traversing the internet, showed multiple people having the same problem. There seems to be a problem with the 'Vector' tag, that should be dynamic if no length was specified. For now, my conclusion is that this cannot be achieved.